# overwite when use ng-init with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use the following loadLocation(asset.id) function to load location for specific  asset with ng-repeat and ng-init ,but I get latest location.city and location.state for all rows

```
   <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets">
        <td>{{asset.name}}</td>
        <td>{{asset.obj_type.name}}</td>
        <td ng-init="loadLocation(asset.id)">
             {{location.city}}
        </td>
        <td>{{location.state}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Angular controller

```
    $scope.loadLocation= function(assetId) {
     Location.locationByIsprimary({assetId: assetId}, function(result) {
                $scope.location=result;
            });
        };
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is `location` inside a different `ngRepeat` - per your code above, `location` seems like one object.

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `location` inside a `scope` only once, you need to create it for each element inside `ng-repeat` array, so that will reflect on html.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="asset in assets">
    <td>{{asset.name}}</td>
    <td>{{asset.obj_type.name}}</td>
    <td ng-init="loadLocation(asset)">
         {{asset.location.city}}
    </td>
    <td>{{asset.location.state}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.loadLocation= function(asset) {
 Location.locationByIsprimary({assetId: asset.id}, function(result) {
            asset.location=result;
        });
    };
```

Comment: I tried but got TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi check the markup which I've added..you need to pass `asset` object in `ng-init` instead of passing `asset.id`

Comment: are you using $resource or $http promise?

Comment: I removed this line  $scope.loadLocation(); from controller,it was performing function so i got undefine error

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi Glad to hear that issue is solved..Thanks :)